# Google Maps appear blank using PhoneGap with Windows Phone 8

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8

I want to display google maps in a PhoneGap app running on Windows Phone.

I followed the following blog post http://www.christianengvall.se/phonegap-and-google-maps/

but the map appears blank like this:[image]

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I got it

the problem was that I missed to assign the **center** attribute to the map options:

```
var mapOptions = {                
zoom: 4,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33, 151),
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
```

this seems strange, you have to assign the map a center location or it will not appear.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

The problem with IE on windows phone 8 release be blocking API.

You must use the domain "maps.google.co.uk" not "maps.googleapis.com"

Google Map API URL working: https://maps.google.co.uk/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false

Also queries tend to be faster.

Answer (score -1):

1/Check that you're app is allow to access internet by inserting in the onDeviceReady function:

```
function onDeviceReady(){
    if (typeof google === 'object' && typeof google.maps === 'object'){
      var map = new GoogleMap();
      map.initialize();
    }else
      alert("You need an internet connection to display the map.")
}
```

2/When I'm only using wifi, my app on the emulator doesn't have internet (but IE on WMP has access). If work if I use both my wifi and ethernet.

3/Check you config.xml, that you have access to google serveur (access tag)